# Azure Service Bus Relay and node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-servicebusrelay

We've been writing services to access our on-premises databases through Azure Service Bus Relay for awhile now. That means that we've had to deploy them as WCF services. Our web site development is moving to node.js and I would like to begin deploying our API services on node as well. However, while the Azure NPM package has good support for queues/topics on Azure Service Bus, I can find no mention of the relaying capabilities. I've had a look at the code for the Azure SDK on github, but again, relay seems to be conspicuously absent.

Is it possible to use Azure Service Bus Relay with a node.js backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Azure support Node.js. You can find the infomration from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-node-get-started). This [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-relay/tree/master/samples/Hybrid%20Connections/Node) is the samples for Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, Relay only supports a WCF service. You can try to use [Clemens Vasters' post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clemensv/archive/2009/11/18/port-bridge.aspx) on Port Bridge to get your scenario working. In his post, he describes creating a WCF client / service that will forward requests to a specific port.